# Problema al cambiar el formato del boton

Tags: html, css

Tengo un botón en el cual tiene una posición que indica una zona. Tiene una animación que al hacer click se despliega y tiene la info de la zona. Estoy tratando de agregar un rombo como para lograr el efecto de icono `location`.

**Rombo CSS**

```
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
```

El efecto que quiero lograr en el botón es de un icono de `location`, que no afecte la animación que es lo que me esta pasando.

Si bien esto es una imagen, quiero lograr el efecto en **css**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
div, img, footer {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1 {font-size: 36pt;}
h2 {font-size: 24pt;}
h3 {font-size: 18pt;}
h4 {font-size: 16pt;}
h5 {font-size: 14pt;}
h6 {font-size: 12pt;}
p {font-size: 12pt; margin-bottom: 12pt;}
strong {
font-weight: 900;
font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #e5e5e5;
}

a {
transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
color: #dff3fd;
}
a:visited {color: #dff3fd;}
li.active a, a:hover, a:active {color: #e5e5e5;}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.distribution-map > img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
z-index: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
border: 3px solid #7fcff7;
}
.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 172px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
```

```html
<div class="distribution-map">
<!--img src="mapafondo.png"-->
<button class="map-point" style="top:530%;left:59%">
<div class="content">
<div class="centered-y">
<h2>Villa Constitucion</h2>
<p>Lugar...</p>
</div>
</div>
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola 4utophovi4, con el texto de la pregunta, no termina de quedar claro cuál es el efecto que quieres conseguir. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para añadir algo más de detalle? ¿Cuándo/Cómo quieres el  rombo?

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, yo lo edite

Comment: Sigo sin comprender el efecto que quieres. ¿Quieres que el botón se convierta en eso? ¿quieres que eso sea el botón y se expanda a un cuadrado?

Comment: Quiero que el boton no sea un circulo, sino que se paresca al icono de posicion, perp no se como hacerlo porque afecta al resto del box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una cosa que podrías intentar y que no cambiaría mucho tu código sería:

- Añadir un `border-radius` al botón para que todas las esquinas sean circulares menos 1 (de ese modo obtienes algo parecido al marcador que indicas)
- Rotar el botón para que la punta del marcador apunte hacia abajo (esto lo puedes hacer el en `transform` usando `rotate`).
- Añadir un círculo al marcador usando `background-shadow` o algún pseudo-elemento como `::before` o `::after` (en mi caso opté por éste último).

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando. La animación se ve bien, aunque puedes cambiarla para que se ajuste más a lo que buscas (en especial los tiempos y los retrasos en las animaciones):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
}

.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.distribution-map>img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #7fcff7;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background:white;
  top: 50%;
  left:  50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active::before,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus::before {
  display: none;
}

.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 172px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25 ease-in-out, transform 0.25s;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
```

```html
<div class="distribution-map">
  <!--img src="mapafondo.png"-->
  <button class="map-point" style="top:530%;left:59%">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="centered-y">
        <h2>Villa Constitucion</h2>
        <p>Lugar...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro! Solo me queda ajustar bien las posiciones y listo!